# Redirection and Piping

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, console

I am a beginner in java and taking the course *Algorithm*, which is provided by Princeton. I am stuck at *redirection and piping* on page 40 in chapter 1.

I use notepadd++ with nppexec to run java, and my execute is written as

```
NPP_SAVE
javac -encoding UTF-8 "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
echo
echo ==========编译成功后开始运行========== 
java -cp "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY);D:\Program Files\java\jdk\lib\algs4.jar" "$(NAME_PART)"
```

However when I use redirection symbol > and < such as

```
NPP_SAVE
javac -encoding UTF-8 "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
echo
echo ==========编译成功后开始运行========== 
java -cp "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY);D:\Program Files\java\jdk\lib\algs4.jar" "$(NAME_PART)" largeW.txt < largeT.txt
```

the program doesn't work. So I think symbol > and < may be used in cmd, and I want to know how to redirect with nppexec.

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

---

This example is from the book on page 9:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BinarySearch 
{
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a)
    {
       int lo = 0;
       int hi = a.length - 1;
       while (lo <= hi)
       {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if      (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
       }
       return -1;
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
        In in = new In("G:\\java\\1.1\\binarysearch\\BinarySearch.txt");
        int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

       while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) 
       {
            int key = StdIn.readInt();            
            if (BinarySearch.rank(key, whitelist)!= -1)              StdOut.println("here it is\n");
           else                                             StdOut.println("where it is\n");
       }
    }
  }
```

Execute of nppexec is

```
NPP_SAVE
javac -encoding UTF-8 "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
echo
echo ==========编译成功后开始运行========== 
java -cp "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY);D:\Program Files\java\jdk\lib\algs4.jar" "$(NAME_PART)" largeW.txt < largeT.txt
```

The largeW.txt and largeT.txt have some integers in them.

However this execute doesn't read two txts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regrettably, you don't say precisely what you are attempting to do.

What you have written *should* provide the program `java` with input from the file `data.txt`. In all probability, `java` ignores the input as it has all the information it needs from the remaining parameters.

If you want to supply `data.txt` as input to *whatever the java program is* then try using `^<` to tell `cmd` that the `<` is data, not a directive for `cmd`.

If that doesn't work, then you'd need to explain further what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I will complete my question. Thank you for pointing out this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe run it directly from cmd without using nppexec? 
To compile javac .java and run it java  < data.txt

Comment: Actually I have used cmd to run redirection such as < and >, and there is no problem. I am think how to use nppexec to implement this...

Comment: @redFIVE e... I don't know what do you mean... I think command line is behind  "$(NAME_PART)"...